# Blurry reflections in Blender 2.8 Beta

Tags: cycles-render-engine

So I have Metallic to 1 and Roughness to 0 in the new Principled BDSF for my spheres in this attached image (My first render from Blender - yey!). But in the reflections of this image everything is pixelish (even the edges of the lamps as well as the HDRI bg-image).

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug? 
(I am new to Blender and used to work in Max so it might be me).

[image: See the edges of my lamps and the bg-image inside the reflective spheres]

Comment: First and most importantly are the spheres set to smooth shading? (if that was not it then) Do you have the denoiser on? What is the resolution of the HDR? How many faces are in the spheres? Any sub division modifier?

Comment: Thanks David!
It was a noob mistake from me. I had the Subdivision Surface Modifier set to high in the vieport but low in the render. So turning it up solved the problem. Maybe keep the post here if someone else runs into the same problem. :)